# Need help in writing data to csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, io

I am using the following code for appending data to a csv file using java:

```
fw.append("Company Name");
fw.append(',');
fw.append(',');
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Addres");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Phones");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Faxes");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Websites");
fw.append(',');
fw.append('\n');
fw.append(companyName);
fw.append(',');
fw.append(address);
fw.append(',');
fw.append(phones);
fw.append(',');
fw.append(faxes);
fw.append(',');
fw.append(websites);
fw.append(',');
fw.append('\n');
fw.flush();
```

But I am not getting the result in the csv file in the proper format as required as per the code above specified.

Please help me in solving the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: could you be more specific about what you're seeing?

Comment: post the format this code is producing and state why you think the format produced is incorrent

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this, consider leveraging an open source solution that already addresses the generic CSV writing problem:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: but by using this method what is the problem.Please answer this

Comment: In the same vein as this answer, i have had good luck with http://kasparov.skife.org/csv/ (also open source)

Comment: @Ankur: By using this method, you can focus on getting your data into a proper in-memory structure and letting CSVWriter deal with the details of encoding that to disk (in a proper CSV manner, leveraging CSV-relevant escapes, encoding, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: not necessarily.  It depends on the application.  Locales that use ',' as a decimal separator (1,23) often use ';' between records.  Locales that don't (1.23) often use ',' between records.

Answer (score 0):

```
fw.append("Company Name");
              fw.append(','); // <-- extra
              fw.append(','); // <-- extra
              fw.append(',');
              fw.append("Addres");
```

This creates extra fields in your csv, and offsets your headers from their corresponding rows.

```
fw.append('\n');
              fw.append(companyName);  
              fw.append(',');   //  <-- only one comma, not three
              fw.append(address);
              fw.append(',');
              fw.append(phones);
```